# Получить значения из bson array object

Tags: php, mongodb

у меня имеется массив, в котором есть поле values, который имеет такую структуру

```
MongoDB\Model\BSONArray Object ( [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [0] => MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object ( [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( [name] => %1548142370673% [value] => 321312 ) ) )
```

Как я могу получить силами Php ключ(name)  и его значение (321312) ?